# "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html" Flask error making an .exe

Tags: python, flask, exe

i'm trying to make and .exe file.

I create it correctly, but when I execute it I get the following error:

```
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
  File "site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
  File "site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
  File "<frozen captchaHarv>", line 36, in solve
  File "site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 138, in render_template
  File "site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 930, in get_or_select_template
  File "site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 883, in get_template
  File "site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
  File "site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 117, in load
  File "site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 60, in get_source
  File "site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 89, in _get_source_fast
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html
```

my code for running index.html (line 36) :

```
    return render_template('index.html', sitekey=sitekey)
```

my folder is like this:

folder test
file.exe

folder templates
index.html

does anyone know where i'm wrong?
thank you so much

Comment: try `templates/index.html` instead

Comment: already tried ... it doesn't work